# AS3 - Move MovieClip across screen

Tags: actionscript-3

I've 3 different MovieClips that I need to move at the same time across the screen. (From bottom to top) 
What is the best way of doing this **without** using a tweening class like Caurina?

Thank you for tips.

Comment: Try [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite) : `yourClip.y = stage.stageHeight;TweenLite.to(yourClip,1,{y:0});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an event listener to the parent container of the display objects which listens for the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event. On each `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event you simply decrement the `y` property of the display objects like in the following example.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(width="600", height="500")]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _squares:Vector.<Square>;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _squares = new Vector.<Square>();

            var redSquare:Square = new Square(0xFF0000, 100);
            redSquare.x = 0; 
            redSquare.y = 400;
            addChild(redSquare);

            var greenSquare:Square = new Square(0x00FF00, 100);
            greenSquare.x = 300; 
            greenSquare.y = 300;
            addChild(greenSquare);

            var blueSquare:Square = new Square(0x0000FF, 100);
            blueSquare.x = 500; 
            blueSquare.y = 100;
            addChild(blueSquare);

            _squares.push(redSquare, greenSquare, blueSquare);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        }// end function

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            for each(var square:Square in _squares)
            {
                if (square.y > 0) square.y -= 5;

            }// end for

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class Square extends Sprite
{
    public function Square(color:uint, size:Number)
    {
        graphics.beginFill(color);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end function
```

I think you'd be making life easier for yourself though if you simply used Greensock's [Tweening platform](http://www.greensock.com/v11/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate them in Flash IDE with frames and tweenings.
Also you can animate them programmatically yourself. Place every movie clip at the bottom of the screen, write some code that moves your movieClips a little to the top of the screen and gets called periodically (using Timer, EnterFrame event listener or setInterval), stop calling this code when all movieClips reached the top (using Timer.stop(), removeEventListener or clearInterval).
I don't see why you might need to do that because there are many tweening libraries that do all this for you.