# matchstick puzzle in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create a matchstick puzzle. But I'm struggling with it.

the puzzle is like this

[image]

the player will have to move only 6 matches to get 3 squares

their are two solution for this

first one:

[image]

second :

[image]

i actually do not know how to accomplish this. If anyone here can provide me any help i'll be thankful.

thank you in advance.

this is what i did so far

```
var totalStick:int = 0; //create a var to store how many buttons there are
//loop through each child of the current timeline
var j:int = numChildren;
while(j--){
    //if the child's name starts with 'piece'
    if(getChildAt(j).name.indexOf("piece") == 0){
        //add the click listener
        getChildAt(j).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick,false,0,true);
        totalStick++; //increase the total buttons variable by 1
    }
}
var clickArray:Array = [];

function buttonClick(e:Event):void {

}
```

created a matchstick movieclip.

i arranged my movieclips to form the initial layout and assigned instance names to the matchstick movieclips.  Then i  added click event listeners to each one.
Now i want on click to move the clicked matchstick to a 'removal' pile.  (clicking on a removed matchstick should return it to its original position.)
the idea is that the player can move only 6 matchstick to form 3 squares.
when clicking on any matchstick it will go like for example 
in the bottom the player can also click on them to return them to where ever he wants. after reaching 6 matchstick removal he cannot remove any more matchstick. so if the player want to remove other than the 6 he already removed he has to return one of the 6 matchstick to the game or spot in the gamed to able to remove other one.

Comment: Sorry to point this out, but these kind of questions tend to be severely down-voted because... Well, StackOverflow is a technical forum where developers who stumbled against **specific** technical problem get help from other developers, who is familiar with the problem. Your question is neither technical, nor specific, thus not fits StackOverflow. What you need is to learn how to program in general, then you need some lessons in AS3.

Comment: I agree with Organis. However, if you generally do know how to program - please include in your post what you already tried

Comment: @Organis [forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)?

Comment: @Brian I'm far too lazy to holywar over names. There are questions, and there are answers, and there are discussion threads. Call it all you want.

Comment: @lucidbrot i included what i have already done. thank you in advance.

Comment: You could save original positions and matchsticks inside arrays, or even just save original positions as custom properties for all matchsticks. Then save also f.ex. `.inPile` custom property and adjust it always when clicking a stick. After this it's fairly simple to compare these properties to possible solutions you have made for example in arrays.

Comment: @Organis LOL @ holywar!  I've just gotten used to thinking of it as "the FAQ for the world's programmers", so "forum" just seems odd.  Comment threads do sorta blur the line.

Answer (score -1):

I'll try and formulate your question more generally. What you want to do is to move a movieclip, right?

I have never coded in ActionScript, but googling for "actionscript move movieclip" already gives a few results, including [this adobe help article on positioning](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7df5.html) and [this adobe help article on animating](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0a.html).

The latter link contains a very helpful example and this description:

> The fundamental idea behind scripted animation is that a change needs
>   to take place, and that change needs to be divided into increments
>   over time. It’s easy to make something repeat in ActionScript, using a
>   common looping statement. However, a loop will run through all its
>   iterations before updating the display. To create scripted animation,
>   you need to write ActionScript that performs some action repeatedly
>   over time and also updates the screen each time it runs.
>
> For example, imagine you want to create a simple animation, such as
>   making a ball travel across the screen. ActionScript includes a simple
>   mechanism that allows you to track the passage of time and update the
>   screen accordingly—meaning you could write code that moves the ball a
>   small amount each time, until it reaches its destination. After each
>   move the screen would update, making the cross-Stage motion visible to
>   the viewer.
>
> From a practical standpoint, it makes sense to synchronize scripted
>   animation with the SWF file’s frame rate (in other words, make one
>   animation change each time a new frame displays or would display),
>   since that defines how frequently Flash Player or AIR updates the
>   screen. Each display object has an enterFrame event that is dispatched
>   according to the frame rate of the SWF file—one event per frame. Most
>   developers who create scripted animation use the enterFrame event as a
>   way to create actions that repeat over time. You could write code that
>   listens to the enterFrame event, moving the animated ball a certain
>   amount each frame, and as the screen is updated (each frame), the ball
>   would be redrawn in its new location, creating motion.

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

// draw a circle and add it to the display list 
var circle:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000); 
circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50); 
circle.graphics.endFill(); 
addChild(circle); 

// When this animation starts, this function is called every frame. 
// The change made by this function (updated to the screen every 
// frame) is what causes the animation to occur. 
function fadeCircle(event:Event):void 
{ 
    circle.alpha -= .05; 

    if (circle.alpha <= 0) 
    { 
        circle.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeCircle); 
    } 
} 

function startAnimation(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    circle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeCircle); 
} 

circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startAnimation);
```

So, the basic idea is to move the matchstick a little every time the screen updates. Let's say you want to take a very simple approach, you could just decrease the y coordinate of the matchstick movieclip by some constant whenever the frame is updated, until it reaches the baseline (0 I assume). Then you can deregister the Event Listener so that it stops moving.

Making the matchstick move back up would work similarly - you would check if the matchstick has a y coordinate of 0, and if yes, do that whole thing for moving upwards until it is at the initial position.

This approach is also [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300485/2550406)

If you didn't want to animate the matchstick, you could also just set its position from `x,y` to `x,0` in your `buttonClick` event listener.